# CORS issues with RESTful service and Mobile Application

Tags: django, sencha-touch-2, django-rest-framework

I have created a RESTful service currently hosted on `http://mydomain:8000`, whereas my mobile application is on `http://mydomain:80`. Unfortunately this is causing problems.

The RESTful service is running in Django REST Framework, whereas the mobile application is in Sencha Touch 2.

I attempted on using `Ext.data.JsonP.request` but, this only allows `GET` where as i need `POST`.

Is it possible somehow to use `JsonP` in `Ext.Ajax.request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a few hours searching more around i came to this solution: https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers